# Android ffmpeg just convert an image file to video file

Tags: android, image, video, ffmpeg

I want to make a sample video file into video for 30 seconds to show. But I can not do it because I'm not good enough with FFmpeg.

My code :

```
 String command[]={
                    "-y",
                    "-r",
                    "1/5",
                    "-i",
                    src.getAbsolutePath(), // only one image file path
                    "-c:v",
                    "libx264",
                    "-vf",
                    "fps=25",
                    "-pix_fmt",
                    "yuv420p",
                    imagesvideoOutput
            };
```

Comment: What failure? does it work on the command line for you?

Comment: Unfortunately. I have not tried it many times. @rogerdpack

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple command for 30 second video from a single image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -vf format=yuv420p -t 30 output.mp4
```

#### Faster, but somewhat more complicated method:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.png -vf fps=25,format=yuv420p -t 30 output.mp4
```

Comment: my ffmpeg just works like this, but I'm doing it wrong. Do you have any other solution [EXAMPLE IMAGE](http://prntscr.com/ibr17w)

Comment: @MehmetKurtgöz Have you verified that the ffmpeg command actually runs? If it does then show the complete log from the ffmpeg command. You can edit your question to include this info.

Comment: Upvoting the answer from LordNeckbeard, as always... :)